# Call back in Objective-C implemented in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, callback, block

I'm using [BWMCoverView](https://github.com/Nihility-Ming/BWMCoverView) in Swift which is originally written in Objective-C and trying to implement this callback in Swift:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^scrolledCallBlock)(int);
```

Just can't figure out how to do it..

Please help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In swift you can use Closure Check this link. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

As per your req. you can do something like this

```
var scrolledCallBlock: ((int) -> Void)?
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more detailed example.  In the Objective-C header, which must be available to Swift via the bridging header:

```
@interface ClassObjC2 : NSObject

-(id)init;
-(void)invokeCB;

@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^scrolledCallBlock)(int);

@end
```

In the Objective-C implementation:

```
@implementation ClassObjC2

-(id)init { return self; }

-(void)invokeCB { self.scrolledCallBlock(1234); }

@end
```

In Swift:

```
var c2 : ClassObjC2 = ClassObjC2()

func callback(i : Int32) ->Void
{
    print("Callback is called with int: \(i)")
}

c2.scrolledCallBlock = callback;  // Commenting this line out will cause "Callback is nil" to be printed.

if c2.scrolledCallBlock != nil
{
    c2.invokeCB()
}
else { print("Callback is nil!!!") }
```

The output:

```
Callback is called with int: 1234
```